# PHP : Filter out text from HTML tags, process it and again place the text where it was (Drupal 9)

Tags: php, filter, text, drupal, processor

I have been trying to find a way to tackle below problem using PHP,
I have a HTML text from CKEditor, I want to replace certain words that I find match with, from a file and add a link to those words. But I have to ignore words from `<i>,<b>,<strong>,<table>,<figure>` etc tags and allow only from `<p>` tag.
Is there a PHP function or logic I can use for achieving this? Please help.

Update:
What I want to achieve is, suppose I have below HTML,

```
    <p>My Text and an Old amoxicillin and more </p>
<p>My Text and an Old2 <h3>My Text under h3 and an Old amoxicillin and more </h3> Word and more </p>
<p>My Text and an Old3 Word and more <table>My Text under table an Old Word and more </table> </p>
<p>My Text and an Old3 Word and more <i>My Text under i and an Old Word and more </i> </p>
<p>My Text and an Old3 Word and more <strong>My Text  under strong and an Old Word and more </strong> </p>
<h3>My Text and an Old Word and more </h3>
```

I want to replace old word to new word from text which is only wrapped in `<p>` and ignore from all the other tags. But also even if it is under

and again wrapped in unwanted tag as above elements it should be ignored as well.

Thanks in advance.

I did not try much yet, but banging my head on wall to figure this out. ;)

Comment: Are `<i>,<b>,<strong>,<table>,<figure>` ever inside `<p>` and if so should they be ignored in those cases?

Comment: You should provide example strings for us to be able to assist you. I'd guess you're trying to highlight search results?

Comment: Sorry @user3783243 I have updated my description it may help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use `preg_match` with regex rules for it

Example

```
$re = '/<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p>/m';
$str = '<i> test</i>
<p>x</p>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

https://regex101.com/r/AdqV0a/1

Also you could be more specific if `<p></p>` can contains any of tags above or not.

There's few options to work around like `preg_match`, `preg_replace` etc...

Code above is just simple example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, let me try this. :)